# Generating curve from curvature

Tags: graphing-functions, curvature

Is there a way to plot a curve in the plane, given the curvature at $(x,y)$ is a function of $(x,y)$, called $C(x,y)$, along with initial conditions?

For example. If a curve originating from (0,0) with the slope 0 has the curvature $C(x,y)=x$ , it would "climb" up the y-axis in a shape resembling a sine curve.

Thanks.

Comment: What is for you the definition of $C (x,y) $.

Comment: Without having looked especially closely at this, if you start with slope $1$ instead of $0$, it wouldn't surprise me if you actually get a sine curve.

Comment: @Arthur For the record, you do not.

Answer (score 1):

Working with curvature $k=\tfrac{1}{R}$ is like working with arc length $s$: it is very uncommon (set apart the circle...) to get tractable expressions in cartesian coordinates.

Oddly, a certain number of curves can be described as the unique solution to a relationship $k=\phi(s)$ (or sometimes $s=\psi(k))$ between $k$ and $s$. These functions $k=\phi(s)$ (or sometimes $s=\psi(k))$ are called **intrinsic equations**. See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_equation) where they are called Cesàro intrinsic equations.

Some examples of intrinsic equations:

- Euler's (or Cornu's) spiral: $\tfrac{1}{r}=k=s^2$ or more generally $k=\tfrac{s^2}{a^2}$ ; see the very nice article (http://levien.com/phd/euler_hist.pdf)
- Logarithmic spiral: $\tfrac{1}{r}=k=\tfrac{a}{s}$ (a constant)
- Circle involute:  $k=\tfrac{a}{\sqrt{s}}.$
- Catenary: $k =\tfrac{a}{s^{2}+a^{2}}.$

**Remarks:**

1) an intrinsic equation defines a curve up to a rotation.

2) intrinsic equations are generalizable to space curves with a third character, the torsion $\tau$ (see Serret-Frenet equations)

Comment: Perhaps i'm missunderstanding, but given $C(x,y)$, initial slope and point of origin, f(x) should have a unique solution.

If $C(x,y)=1$, slope=0 and $f(x)$ originates from (0,0), then $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}-1$.

Comment: This is a particular case (a half circle), and even in this case, you have  a second solution (which is $f_2(x)=\color{red}{ - }\sqrt{1-x^2}-1$, the other half circle).

Comment: I am going to add to my answer some remarkable examples of intrinsic equations.

Comment: Frankly, they are both part of the same curve $f(x)^2+x^2=1$. In this context, i immagine the construction of a curve as an iterative process with it being traced out depending on preceding slope and curvature. I do not see why the curve should have more than one solution.

Comment: All right, I thought you had given as an objective to get cartesian forms $y=f(x)$. One thing is certain, intrinsic equations are a very handy way to work with certain curves and (important !) they generalize to space curves with a third character, the torsion $\tau$  (see Serret Frenet equations)

Comment: I have modified my answer. I do not argue any more about the fact that a unique curve can be obtained in cartesian equations (after all, a condition on a curvature gives a differential equation, with, most often, a unique solution in a certain neighborhood. I just insisted on the fact that intrinsic equations may provide an alternative tool...

Comment: I will have to read into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at this in the complex plane where it might be easier to comprehend. As pointed out elsewhere on this page, the curvature $\kappa$ is typically expressed as a function of the arc length, $s$ or the tangent angle, $\theta$. The curve can then be expressed as

$$z(s)=\int e^{i\int \kappa(s)ds}ds$$

Since the tangent angle $\theta=\int \kappa(s)ds$, we can also say

$$z(\theta)=\int \frac{e^{i\theta}}{\kappa(\theta)}d\theta$$

Now, when $z$ is expressed parametrically, say, $z=z(u)$, then it can be shown that the curvature is given by

$$\kappa=\frac{\mathfrak{Im}\{\dot z^*\ddot z\}}{|\dot z|^3}$$

I do not see a clear path to obtaining $z$ from $\kappa(z)$.

If we look at the equation in Cartesian coordinates, and allow that the curve is given by $y=f(x)$, then the curvature and signed curvature, $k$ are given by

$$
\kappa=\frac{|y''|}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}\\
k=\frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}
$$

Again, I can't see a path to $y(\kappa)$.

References

Zwikker, C. (1968). *The Advanced Geometry of Plane Curves and Their Applications*, Dover Press.

[Wikipedia: Curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature)